# Questions about fstream only reading in 1 structure

Tags: c++, struct, fstream, binaryfiles

I have the following problem: my program that uses `fstream` doesn't seem to be able to write more than 1 data `struct` into my .dat file.

Below is my code, I've only been able to add 1 set of data. When I tried to add another, it worked but did not write out. Any idea why?

For example, I run this function, type in the details, and successfully entered 1 set of booking information, and info is stored in my .dat file.

When I re-run this function, type in the details, the 2nd set of booking information is NOT recorded in my .dat file. Therefore my .dat file ends up having only the first entry, and not storing the subsequent entries

```
void booking::bkForm(fstream& afile, bForm& b)
{
    customer c;
    GM g;
    GM::holidayPackages h;
    char fname [30];
    char lname [30];
    char address [50];
    char date [30];
    char req [100];
    int pid, position, choice;
    bool iStat = false;
    bool dStat = false;
    int noOfRecords = getNoBFRecords(afile);
    int q = g.getNoOfHRecords(afile);
    cout << "Please Fill Up Required Booking Form." << endl;
    cout << "Please enter your first name: ";
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    cin.getline(fname, 30);
    cout << "Please enter your last name: ";
    cin.getline(lname,30);
    cout << "Please enter your address: ";
    cin.getline(address,50);

    cout << "\nThese are the available Packages to choose from." << endl;
    g.printHolidayPackages(afile, h);
    afile.open("holidayPackages.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);
    while(iStat == false)
    {
        cout << "\nPlease enter the Package ID of the tour that you want to join." << endl;
        cout << "Package ID: ";
        cin >> pid;
        for(int i = 0; i < q; i++)
        {
                afile.read (reinterpret_cast <char *>(&h), sizeof(h));
                if(pid == h.holID)
                {
                    iStat = true;
                    position = i;
                }
        }
        if(iStat == false)
        {
            cout << "ID not found, please enter valid Package ID" << endl;
        }
    }

    while(choice!=1 && choice!=2)
    {
        afile.seekg ((position) * sizeof (GM::holidayPackages), ios::beg);
        afile.read (reinterpret_cast <char *>(&h), sizeof (h));
        cout << "\nPleasse choose the Date of tour that you want to join." << endl;
        cout << "1) " << h.holDate1 << endl;
        cout << "2) " << h.holDate2 << endl;
        cout << "Your choice: ";
        cin >> choice;
        if(choice == 1)
        {
            strcpy(date, h.holDate1);
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy(date, h.holDate2);
        }
    }

    cout << "\nPlease State Any Special Requirement That You Have Below." << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    cin.getline(req, 100);

    afile.close();

    afile.open("bookingInfo.dat", ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);

    strcpy(b.bfName, fname);
    strcpy(b.blName, lname);
    strcpy(b.bAddress, address);
    strcpy(b.bDate, date);
    strcpy(b.bStatus, "Unchecked");
    strcpy(b.bReq, req);
    b.packageID = pid;

    srand(time(NULL));
    int a = rand () % 100000+899990; // random 6 digit number as booking ref.
    for(int k = 0; k < noOfRecords; k++)
    {
        afile.read (reinterpret_cast <char *>(&b), sizeof(b));
        while(a == b.bookingRef)
        {
                a = rand () % 100000+899990;
        }

    }
    b.bookingRef = a;

    cout << "Booking Submitted."  << endl;
    cout << "Please take down the booking reference no : " << b.bookingRef << endl;
    cout << "You will need the reference number to check the status of your booking" << endl;

    afile.write(reinterpret_cast <const char *>(&b), sizeof(b));
    afile.close();

}
```

Tthis is some sample output. There is only 1 result instead of a few.

```
==========================================================
Details Of Booking Number: 0
===========================================================
Booking Reference no: 966373
Customer Name: Cheryl Tan
Customer Address: St24 Tampines
Package ID of Package Booked: 9102
Package Date Choosen: 02032014
Special Requirements: none
Booking Status: Unchecked
```

Answer (score 0):

its okay, i realise my error.

the error being i called for read, but i've only opened the file for write/append.

corrected code fragment will be like this..

```
afile.open("bookingInfo.dat", ios::in | ios::binary); //changed here to read
    srand(time(NULL));
    int a = rand () % 100000+899990; // random 6 digit number as booking ref.
    for(int k = 0; k < noOfRecords; k++)
    {
        afile.read (reinterpret_cast <char *>(&b), sizeof(b));
        while(a == b.bookingRef)
        {
                a = rand () % 100000+899990;
        }

    }
    afile.close(); // close read

    afile.open("bookingInfo.dat", ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary); // open append
    strcpy(b.bfName, fname);
    strcpy(b.blName, lname);
    strcpy(b.bAddress, address);
    strcpy(b.bDate, date);
    strcpy(b.bStatus, "Unchecked");
    strcpy(b.bReq, req);
    b.packageID = pid;
    b.bookingRef = a;

    cout << "Booking Submitted."  << endl;
    cout << "Please take down the booking reference no : " << b.bookingRef << endl;
    cout << "You will need the reference number to check the status of your booking" << endl;

    afile.write(reinterpret_cast <const char *>(&b), sizeof(b));
    afile.close(); // close append
```